# Visual counter relative to scroll position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a project i have to make a visual counter with html and javascript that counts down from 150 to 0 relative to the scrolling position of the window.

I'm not entirely sure how i should go about doing this but here's what i have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="meterCounter">
    <label class="number">150</label>
    <label class="rotated">mtr.</label>
</span>
```

**JS:**

```
// calculate page height (keeping element position in mind):
var offset = $(".meterCounter").offset().top;
var pageHeight = $(document).height() - offset;

// calculate how many pixels user should scroll until html changes:
var divide = pageHeight / 150;

count = 150;

$(document).scroll(function(){

    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    // (magic if statement here that determines when html should change)

        count--;
        $(".number").html(count);
        divide = divide + divide;


});
```

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/d160vLqm/16/) of what i have atm (by DelightedD0D, thanks btw!)

I've searched around the interwebs but can't find a good solution to this little problem here.

Help and advice on how to solve this mystery is much appreciated!

(note: not asking for people to write code for me, just some solid advice or a push in the right direction! :] ).

Thanks alot!

***edit:**
i should add, at the bottom of the page the counter needs to be at 0 and at the top it needs to be back to 150, so, in my mind i have to update the html each time i scroll X amount of pixels (X being the "divide" variable).

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have? Seems to [work fine in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/d160vLqm/16/)

Comment: @DelightedD0D it does work indeed but it is not accurate, meaning at the bottom of the page the counter also needs to be at 0 and at the top back to 150.

Comment: you need to use the `scrollPosition` and calculate where it is in relation to the actual height. The problems now are that you do not take into account the direction of the scroll and also the fact that each scroll is not for the same amount of pixels. So you cannot really increment by 1 your counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment that you need to calculate where the `scrollPosition` is relative to the total height

A sample

```
// calculate page height (keeping element position in mind):
var offset = $(".meterCounter").offset().top;
var pageHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

// calculate how many pixels user should scroll until html changes:
var count = 150,
    divide = pageHeight / count;

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(),
        relevantToHeight = scrollPosition*count/pageHeight ;

    // (magic if statement here that determines when html should change)
    $(".number").html(count - Math.round(relevantToHeight));
});
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/d160vLqm/18/

(*keep in  mind that on window resize you need to recalculate most of the cached variables*)

Comment: This is amazing! works just how i need it to! thanks alot friendo!

Comment: **Warning**: You shouldn't subtract value of `offset` from `pageHeight`. That way, moving counter a bit from the top of the page, may cause it to indicate values below 0. [See this erroneous behavior in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdegj1fw/).

Comment: @Przemek nice catch. You are right, i corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Actually @Gaby aka G. Petrioli answer is a bit flawed. Value in variable `pageHeight` shouldn't be reduced by counter's distance from the top of the document, which is stored in variable `offset`. You can observe the resulting erroneous behavior, by changing counter's position, removing `Math.round()` (so that the error is not covered by approximation) and scrolling to the bottom. Or just [see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/bdegj1fw/) right now.</s> (fixed).

Here is my solution using plain JavaScript. It includes recalculation on window's resize, too.

```js
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');

function updateCounter() {
  'use strict';
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  counter.textContent = 150 - document.documentElement.scrollTop / height * 150;
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', updateCounter);
window.addEventListener('resize', updateCounter);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 1000%;
}
#counter {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<span id="counter">150</span>
```

([**See it on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yvp9fxmc/)).

Few notes on why this JavaScript looks the way it looks:

- `'use strict'` is to opt into so called [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (MDN).
- `document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight` is height that we are interested in. It is height of the entire document reduced by the height of viewport. Why do we need that reduction? Because whatever is our current scroll position, we will never scroll completely out of document, i.e. we will always see some portion of it and that portion equals viewport's height.
  Another thing: It is stored in variable for readability, but in fact it could be put in place of `height` in the next line, as that is its only appearance.
- `document.documentElement.scrollTop / height` will give us our scroll position relatively to document's height, i.e. how many percent of document we have scrolled. It will be number in range from 0 to 1, but we are interested in range from 0 to 150, hence multiplying. And all of that is subtracted from 150, because we want to count from 150 to 0, not the opposite.
- If you want counter to display only integers, put the whole statement after `counter.textContent =` inside `Math.round()`.
- The two last lines attach function that updates counter to events of scroll and resize. That way, whenever we scroll or resize window, counter-updating function will be invoked.

I personally find this approach much clearer from the jQuery one that was posted here. And it has better performance too, of course.

**UPDATE**: Changed two occurrences of `document.body` to `document.documentElement`, because the manner in which at least one of them was used here was deprecated and stopped working.

Comment: wow nice! i'll definitly try this out too thanks alot! really helpfull!