# Change image while scrolling the mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var myimages=[
  "images/dad.png",
  "images/terminal.png",
  "images/hi.png",
  "images/hengameh.png",
  "images/shrinedefense.png"
]
var slideshow=document.getElementById("slideshowers")
var nextslideindex=0
function rotateimage(e){
  var evt=window.event || e
  var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta
  nextslideindex=(delta<=-120)? nextslideindex+1 : nextslideindex-1
  nextslideindex=(nextslideindex<0)? myimages.length-1 : (nextslideindex>myimages.length-1)? 0 : nextslideindex
  slideshow.src=myimages[nextslideindex]
  if (evt.preventDefault)
    evt.preventDefault()
  else
    return false
}
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"

if (slideshow.attachEvent)
  slideshow.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, rotateimage)
else if (slideshow.addEventListener)
  slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, rotateimage, false)
```

```html
<img id="slideshowers" class="cover-images" src="http://www.ammaryar.ir/images/dad.png" />
```

Hi, I want to change the image, while scrolling the mouse wheel.
You can find what I want in the following link:
http://www.ammaryar.ir
There is a lantern on the right side, I have four lantern with different colors. I want to change these lanterns while you scrolling the mouse wheel.
I did something, but it's not working properly. if you move your mouse on the lantern picture and trying to scroll, images change by random and repeat.
I don't what to change randomly and repeat, I have 5 menu tabs and I that each menu have specific image while you scroll mouse wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const pageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight,
      imgElement = document.getElementById('img'),
      images     = ['http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1',
                   'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/2',
                   'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/3',
                   'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/4'];
let   lastImage  = 0;

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let index = parseInt(document.documentElement.scrollTop / pageHeight * images.length);
  index = Math.min(index, images.length - 1); // Prevent few pixel overflow

  if (index !== lastImage) { // If we need to display different image
    lastImage = index;
    imgElement.src = images[lastImage];
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 700vh;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1"/>
```

Quoting myself from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35923228/959552):

> - `document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight` is height that we are interested in. It is height of the entire document
>     reduced by the height of viewport. Why do we need that reduction?
>     Because whatever is our current scroll position, we will never scroll
>     completely out of document, i.e. we will always see some portion of it
>     and that portion equals viewport's height.
> - `document.documentElement.scrollTop / pageHeight` will give us our scroll position relatively to document's height, i.e. how many percent
>     of document we have scrolled. It will be number in range from 0 to 1,
>     but we are interested in range from 0 to 4, hence multiplying.

Comment: @R.Tanha: What is exactly not working? What browser (including version) are you using? Are images showing up, at least? Are there any errors in developer's console (F12 and then *Run code snippet*)?